# how to set a program to run automatically once a day in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop

I am a newbie to programming So I need lot of support from my friends I am creating a windows forms application and I need that program to run automatically once a day and need to close itself after 2 minutes of the execution how to do it....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need that program to run automatically once a day

You can use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766428(v=ws.11).aspx).

> need to close itself after 2 minutes of the execution

You can implement in your application using many different approaches.
For instance, since you write WinForms applications, you can use [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I think window service is much better than window forms in this scenario

Comment: @DeepakSharma As for me, I see no advantage in Windows Service when application should be run only 2 minutes per day (0.1% uptime). I would use Console Application for such short tasks anyway. Moreover, the OP tells that he writes Windows Forms application, it is impossible to run Windows Service with WinForms GUI context.

Comment: thanx machan but I want program itself run automatically and close automatically

Answer (score 2):

I would like to take the below approach.

1. Write console application. and add appropriate log message so that you can understand how it goes. if the application need any parameter then pass it from command line or put in a file so that the app can read the file and run automatically.
2. Add the app to Windows schedule task and monitor log regularly.

if the input parameter changes everyday then just update the input file when necessary.

Hope it will give you a idea.

Thanks.

Ruhul